# What verb does the conjugation 満つる come from and what does it mean?

Tags: conjugations

In the Tales series this verb is used as a spell chant:

> 天光**満つる**所に我は在り。

But when I type in みつる　＋　Ｓｐａｃｅ　I get only 満. When I search 満つる in the dictionary it doesn't recognize it as a conjugation： [https://jisho.org/search/満つる](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%BA%80%E3%81%A4%E3%82%8B) . Is this something archaic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the attributive form of archaic 満{み}つ, whose conjugation goes みち・ず、みち・て、みつ、みつる・とき、みつれ・ば、みち・よ. (The online dictionary in your link mistakes it as godan and gives wrong "inflection". Be careful.)

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to achieve the same meaning in today's time, would I be using 満ちる unconjugated？

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "unconjugated" but anyway it's みちる and its attributive form is the same as the terminal one.

Comment: I meant uninflected, just the terminal form of the verb. But I understand now